# Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric in XML data retrieving

Tags: sql-server, xml, xml-parsing

I'm working with code which generates a SQL view from an XML input. Some of the fields cause data converting errors (nvarchar to numeric and string to date or time). I have tried to cast the values but looks like the error occurs before the casting, in the moment that data is retrieved from the XML. I include the fields with problems by types:

Error:

> Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric

Code:

```
Threshold = ISNULL(promo.value('Threshold[1]', 'decimal(7,2)'), 0.0), 
ChargeAmount = ISNULL(promo.value('Amount[1]', 'decimal(10,2)'), 0), 
Maximum = ISNULL(promo.value('Maximum[1]', 'decimal(7,2)'), 0),
```

Error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Code:

```
StartDate = header.value('BeginDateTime[1]', 'date'), 
StartTime = header.value('BeginDateTime[1]', 'time'), 
EndDate = header.value('EndDateTime[1]', 'date'), 
EndTime = header.value('EndDateTime[1]', 'time'),
```

These fields are included in a SELECT clause with at least 90 fields and the others don't have problem. So, anyone knows which modifications i have to make to these lines to avoid the errors? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the declared type for "Threshold"?

Comment: You likely have invalid data in those fields. What version of SQL server are you using? If 2012 or above, you can change the lines that are causing the errors to 'nvarchar' temporarily in order see what the values are, and add a filter to your where clause using TRY_CONVERT to see where the invalid values are. For example: add to your where clause something like: `WHERE TRY_CONVERT(decimal(7,2), ISNULL(promo.value('Threshold[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 0.0)) is null`  Read more on Try_Convert here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx

Comment: BateTech, indeed i changed the values to nvarchar and confirmed that the view is retrieving invalid data. The date and time fields are receiving just numbers or empty values and the decimal fields fields are receiving empty. In the case of the datetimes, the XML has correct data so i have to check the way that the view is getting it. Thanks.

Comment: We need to see the **XML Input** to see what those elements look like in the XML, to be able to explain why those conversions fail....

Comment: Thanks to all. The errors occurs due to data inconsistency in the DB. With proper data it works fine.